# Why does the read command not take interactive options when run by sh?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, read

I want to download a provisioning script that reads some configuration parameters via `read`, and execute it:

```
curl http://example.com/provisioning.sh | sh
```

The problem is, that the `read` command in the script is call with the `-i` parameter to provide a default:

```
read -p "Name: " -i joe name
echo $name
```

If I download the script, set the `+x` permission and run it, everything's fine.

If I run it with `cat provisioning.sh | sh` or `sh provisioning.sh`, it fails with:

```
read: Illegal option -i
```

Why wouldn't read support providing a default if it's run via sh?

But whatever, I'll remove the `-i`, being left with

```
read -p "Name: " name
echo $name
```

Now if I run the script via `cat provisioning.sh | sh`, it won't do anything. Why is that?

Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you pipe the output of `curl` into `sh` you're making the script text be standard input of the shell, which takes it in as commands to run. After that, there's nothing left to `read`. Even if it were to try, it wouldn't get anything from the terminal input, because it's not connected to it. The pipe has replaced standard input for the `sh` process.

The next problem is that `read -i` is [**not** a POSIX sh feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/read.html), but rather an extension supported by `bash`. [Ubuntu uses `dash`](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh), a minimal POSIX-compliant shell with minimal extensions, as `/bin/sh` by default. That's why it rejects the `-i` option specifically (although it does support `-p`).

If you're using a more capable shell yourself, you can try something like:

```
bash <(curl http://example.com/provisioning.sh)
```

which creates a pipe for `bash` to read the output of `curl` from and provides it as the script file argument. In this case, the standard input of the script is still connected to the terminal, and `read` will work (but note the big caveat below the line).

---

I'll note also that **"`curl | sh`" is [generally](http://blog.existentialize.com/dont-pipe-to-your-shell.html) [frowned](http://output.chrissnell.com/post/69023793377/stop-piping-curl-1-to-sh-1) [upon](http://onethingwell.org/post/9080811280/insecure-installation)** as an obvious security problem, but you know best the situation your script is in.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent answer! `curl | sh` is used by [meteor.com](http://meteor.com) ...

Answer (score 0):

Another, more portable way to accomplish this is to create another file descriptor:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tty
read -u 3 -p "Gimme some stuff: " stuff
```

I found that over here:
https://superuser.com/questions/834502/possible-to-get-a-bash-script-to-accept-input-from-terminal-if-its-stdin-has-bee

In my case I did a quick find replace in my script so that this would work:

```
exec 3<>/dev/tty
read_cmd="read -u 3"

$read_cmd -p "name: " my_name
$read_cmd -p "email: " my_email
$read_cmd -s -p "password: " my_password
```